# Checkout: drop down menus issue with white text on white background

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I've found basically the same issue i was having that someone else posted.

Where should I add that code?

[Woocommerce Option Box text white on white background, style cant override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43256613/woocommerce-option-box-text-white-on-white-background-style-cant-override)

[image]

Comment: CSS can either go into your child theme's style.css file or into the CSS section of the [WordPress customizer](https://en.support.wordpress.com/customizer/).

Comment: Thanks for the reply,
That's what i thought but in that link i posted the guy said this
"Option can't be styled with css. WooCommerce uses jQuery for selects"
I'm trying to find where he's talking about

Comment: That link you posted has CSS modifying a jquery object instead of a HTML form element.  The CSS still goes in either of the same places I mentioned previously.

Comment: I feel dumb..
I'll let you know if that fixes it. And thank you so much!

Comment: Justin R your the best!
Thank you so much!
Issue is now solved! You enter the code by going to Appearance / Edit CSS.
I thought i had tried that but i guess not. Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome.  Glad it helped.